# how to make an object visible again in game maker

Tags: game-maker

Fist of all, I'm really sorry for my bad English and I pretty new to game maker .

I have 2 object in the game : obj_apple and obj_door( I  unchecked visible box)
my question is 
how can I make an obj_door visible in the room when all the obj_apple are destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

Object `obj_door`, `Step` event, place code (`Add event` -> `Step` -> `Step` -> tab `Control` -> section `Code`, first icon (Execute code)):

```
if !instance_exists(obj_apple) visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, so you aren't making a check in every step event, is to put the check for the number of `obj_apple` in the `destroy` event of `obj_apple`.

For example, in the `destroy` event of `obj_apple` you would have:

```
if (instance_number(object_index) == 0) {
   with (obj_door) {
      visible = true;
   }
}
```